# Table TR onClick vs. <a> Link on the table

Tags: html, hyperlink, onclick, html-table

I have this DEMO situation:
http://carreradesign.com.br/teste/admin

I'm using a "onClick" on a table  row (tr), but I also have a second link on the X image to delete that row... but when I click on the X link, I'm redirect to the tr link too... How can I use the link on the X without redirect to the link on the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a jQuery event handler for the X button as well. In the event handler for the X button, call `event.stopPropagation();`. This stops the event from bubbling, preventing the parent from handling the event.

An example:

```
$('.xbtn').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...// do stuff
}
```